# How to write class in Powershell that returns exponentiation, pow(3,2)

Tags: powershell

Could you help with script cannot got how to do class that returns the base to the exponent power

Example

```
$SomeClass.Pow(2, 3)
# It must Return:
8

$SomeClass.Pow(8, 2)
64
```

Haven't tried something, because have no idea

Haven't some code

Comment: Why would you need to write such a class if `Math` already exists with exactly that method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mostert notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967167/how-to-write-classin-powershell-that-returns-exponentiation-pow3-2/67967500#comment120132259_67967167), the `[Math]` class already provides this functionality:

```
PS ~> [Math]::Pow(2, 3)
8
```

I'm not sure why this would be necessary, but if you want to provide this functionality through an instance method of a class you define, wrap it like this:

```
class TheThomaszExponentiator
{
    [double]Pow([double]$a, [double]$b)
    {
        return [Math]::Pow($a, $b)
    }
}
```

At which point you can do:

```
PS ~> $exponentiator = [TheThomaszExponentiator]::new()
PS ~> $exponentiator.Pow(2, 3)
8
```

---

If your use case is specifically for large integer exponentiation, you might want to take advantage of the `[bigint]` type instead of `[Math]::Pow()`:

```
PS ~> [math]::Pow(2, 12345)    # too big for a [double], result is positive infinity
∞
PS ~> [bigint]::Pow(2, 12345)  # not too big for a [bigint]
164171010688258216356020741663906501410127235530735881272116103087925094171390144280159034536439457734870419127140401667195510331085657185332721089236401193044493457116299768844344303479235489462436380672117015123283299131391904179287678259173308536738761981139958654880852234908448338817289014166774169869251339379828599748492918775437864739032217778051333882990074116246281269364933724892342134504702491040016637557429810893780765197418589477584716543480995722533317862352141459217781316266211186486157019262080414077670264642736018426998113523445732680856144329876972273300703392584997729207197971083945700345494092400147186997307012069454068489589035676979448169848060836924945824197706493306108258511936030341393221586423523264452449403781993352421885094664052270795527632721896121424813173522474674395886155092203404036730748474781710715745446135468098139831824083259647919175273503681561172684624283384438504776503000432241604550454374116320822227191911322123484085063926350606342197146407841178028071147192533942517270553513988142925976090769695456221159699052583533011331652079347093098173086975483539274464023357456484465482927479569437320368592222760278170306076733438801098370797675711274671054970711442158930561684343135774118741594506702833147396758825015850042983343690345185995956235143825771620543546030664562647854656431302644574119873820215595718618624485232422006575550007068883734241454686368856734496265385908809403972494685137741122866896719678053937285818409751670320140501843039224040735870096889596273419106389103662095318937990625980136711988237421962315266686856089505981438440850638067589321141759499017023839596858455548192000140085142294166987063499024792681334843159790936321351919859758669569200541507612099780909705198902176026219872201715422096090343686272984351441594569506778041062663266799342793856313801540959815845788584759033248828248561586450271172777240971795656082001848115815260930521663167480173886064019118572778281516735157779555888167787064432558595410843987446497881666288423233170060413025924629950477303342180149398926073618582715358742250388958231281694757980523791263699450732952325727664209947786063982561775327638504516918570101319391698412388607603742484414748268389669129118026878969735782286841116842656410574647607524418900720328045377993386279808768990376289424757351052369393977137871998119168898493037938756635621557623138404459266598837784229325799838782026060481496865561757031839002257091802876949248392744175669112242088439883248336310597001257385980776961529351198877747193531054956881808332177946751404038228718567911769630971553915410012677600002457982207465176670752102117002773980548089696530972476439694599881281812973217265853884727906535479745854085338851105144585481994156206497436745899944877732531412541279014300324594890623941145509856940982863769834430048120562966797907114102689879364945689860493474954538422367719507882513166051007352994068319251450666676648368200564329382998758875760414259654004977261309988267319806354856051784553990936610634733375984159028722378614984450255386315585631994503350002142910493190254825610707400589976364985748467955131077971641882672895854571236368282811336220769174784720113331269084746524204124263475054112841630933586166195036115696469686075600480420563557567616835633252622327172811002146392754445051182169805284630259703542633955126179520113059629914229833688535925729676778028406897316106101038469119090984567152591962365415039646394591503830797626339246986057077758611413664914168745375266786298141171496573941614387744125843685677063619782918759823106021054037757857761587472240835040580447360544029064930412569943169729238102162312218687930203068055400275795180972382856696655279408212344832
```